# Requiring class, but the class is undefined when referenced from a different class

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, undefined, require

In node.js server I am requiring 2 classes. One class references the other one, but after trying to instance the class it says the other one is undefined.

I am using node.js with express
I am doing require() this way in main server .js

```
var Card = require('./client/classes/Card.js');
var Unit = require('./client/classes/Unit.js');
var HeroShaggy = require('./client/classes/HeroShaggy.js');
```

HeroShaggy references Card in constructor

```
class HeroShaggy
{
    constructor()
    {
        // error at this line (when doing new HeroShaggy()
        console.log(Card);

...

module.exports = HeroShaggy;
```

Error that "Card is not defined" at the commented line.

I did console.log in server.js (after all requires) and the output is

```
[Function: Card]
[Function: Unit]
[Function: HeroShaggy]

[Function: TestClass] - Class I created in server.js for testing
```

Comment: Does the `HeroShaggy` file `require()` the `Card`?  You have to do it in the file that actually **uses** the import.  You don't just include it at the top level (server.js).

Comment: It did not - this solves server sided issue, but this has created a different problem.

The same class file is used both by server and the client. The client already has variable Card declared and this throws out an error.

Comment: Then you will need to fix your dependency graph.

Comment: How would I be to approach that?

Comment: Ended up doing ```var Card_ = typeof(Card) !== 'undefined' ? Card : require('./Card.js');``` which doesn't seem to be that great of an approach

Comment: I found that to use global scope in node.js you need to use ```global``` object. I used that in main server script and now instead of ```var Card``` there is ```global.Card``` and it works just fine. The question is - is it a good practice?